# Can't change regular expression string

Tags: actionscript-3

I have this function:

```
function tagCheck(tag:String,rez:String):String{
    var regExp:RegExp = /\[user_id\](.*?)\[\/user_id\]/g;
    var matches:Object = regExp.exec(rez);
    return matches[1];
 }
```

I wanna change "user_id" with tag, how can I do that because there are no string in regExp? thank you!

Comment: What do you mean with tag? What will the 'tag' be?

Comment: can you show us what did you try exactly please

Comment: `/\[tag\](.*?)\[\/tag\]/g` ????

Comment: the tag will be one word like error, user_id, time...etc. some words that server will send to my application.

Comment: Why doesn't `/\[error\](.*?)\[\/error\]/g` and `/\[time\](.*?)\[\/time\]/g` work?

Comment: /\[tag\](.*?)\[\/tag\]/g  -> will this change the tag with my parameter string in regExp expresion?

Comment: h2ooooo, yes it work like that but I really want to use function in this case, if is posible :)

Comment: I read something about RegExp = new RegExp(2 param here); first is string and second "flag", I try but no result...:-|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a regex simply by creating a new [`RegExp`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/RegExp.html) class.

> public function RegExp(re:String, flags:String)

```
function tagCheck(tag:String, rez:String) : String {
    var tagRegex:String = tag.replace(new RegExp('[.\\\\+*?\\[\\^\\]$(){}=!<>|:\\' + ('\/' || '') + '-]', 'g'), '\\$&');
    var regExp:RegExp = new RegExp('\\[' + tagRegex + '\\](.*?)\\[\\/' + tagRegex + '\\]', 'g');
    var matches:Object = regExp.exec(rez);
    return matches[1];
}
```

Should work (though untested). [The first line is to make sure that a tag called `my.tag` gets changed into `my\.tag`](http://phpjs.org/functions/preg_quote/).

Comment: thank you for posting,  my second parameter "rez" is the string that must be split. it is something like this: "[user_id]34[\user_id]",

Comment: @user2465147 Yes? What's your point? It's being used in `regExp.exec(rez)`?